# Django Q object is adding extra - IS NOT NULL

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

for the below raw query, I want to build Django ORM query

```
Select * from employee 
WHERE (address_id is not null OR address_id<>'*')
    AND (xyz_id is null OR xyz_id='*')
    AND (abc_id is null OR abc_id='*')
```

So I have build ORM query as below

```
data = Employee.objects.filter(~Q(address_id="23") | Q(address_id__isnull=False),
                            Q(xyz_id__isnull=False) | Q(xyz_id='*'),
                            Q(abc_id__isnull=True) | Q(abc_id=‘*’))
```

and when i print the query, it is showing as below

> SELECT "employee"."id", "employee"."xyz_id", "employee"."abc_id" FROM
> "employee" WHERE ((NOT ("employee"."address_id" = 23 **AND
> "employee"."address_id" IS NOT NULL**) OR "employee"."address_id" IS
> NOT NULL) AND ("employee"."xyz_id" IS NOT NULL OR "employee"."xyz_id"
> = *) AND ("employee"."abc_id" IS NULL OR "employee"."abc_id" = *))

my question is why Q object in Django is adding bolded line in above generated query ? which is not solving for above raw sql criteria.

i am using Django 2.2 version

Kindly advise

Comment: `employe_id` is `adress_id`?

Comment: yes,  edited and changed

Answer (score 1):

If you write `Q(foo=bar)`, then an implicit constraint is that `foo` is not `NULL`, if you negate that however, it will write `NOT (foo = bar)` but if `foo` is `NULL`, then `NOT (foo = bar)` is `NOT (NULL = bar)` which is `NULL`, so this will be filtered out of the queryset. which would thus result in `FALSE` whereas for `NULL`, one would expect that this is `TRUE`.

To thus ensure that `~Q(…)` is the full opposite of `Q(…)`, it thus should add `foo IS NOT NULL` to the condition.

In this specific case however the query optimizer could probably indeed figure out that it is not necessary due to the `address_id IS NOT NULL` later in the query, but here apparently the optimizer does not eliminate that clause.

Comment: OK thank you , is there any other way to write Django ORM query which satisfy the raw query ? , i dont want this condition to be added automatically ==> AND "employee"."address_id" IS NOT NULL